# How to properly create an MP3 file out of an ftypisom-type octet-stream

Tags: python, file, http, audio, mpeg

How can you create an MP3 Audio file from an DASH-encrypted `octet-stream` served by a server? I have already tried to just write all received bytes to a file, but the thereby created audio file can only be played for the first 10 seconds. What am I doing wrong here?

How do I decrypt it and where do I get the decryption key from?

Example Python code:

```py
from requests import get

response = get(URL) #No range defined to fully download the file

#response.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/octet-stream"

response.raise_for_status() #everything is ok (200)

with open("audio.mp3", "wb") as fs:
    fs.write(response.content)
```

The received file has the following file signature: `ftypisom` (`ISO Base Media file (MPEG-4) v1`) and `iso8mp41dashcmfc` (I could not find out what this means)

The following meta-data can be found in the file-header:
`hdlr` `ID32` `ID3` `CPRIV 9` `https://github.com/google/shaka-packager` `5bf8ad5e-release` `utrak` `\tkhd`...

Comment: maybe server can create only 10 seconds. For example Google Text-To-Speech generates only 10 seconds and for longer audio it needs special method.